# Site with different headers in magento?

Tags: xml, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I am new to magento CMS. My problem is that in my e-commerce project, I have two headers:

**1. Homepage Header only for homepage.**

**2. Normal header for rest of the pages.**

I am developing a theme from scratch and I am confused where to have the second header to my rest of the pages. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have several methods to do this:First of all set header for all pages by editing header.phtml(copy this one to your theme and edit). Then override header of home page(follow the steps below)

```
1. Enter to the admin and open the editor of the CMS pages:

2. Open for editing the page “Home page”:

3.Go to the tab “Design”:

4. Add the following text in the section “Layout Update XML”:

<reference name="header">
    <block type="page/header" name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/customheader.phtml</template></action> 
    </block> 
</reference>
```

**OR**

Add this code to your `local.xml`

```
    <cms_index_index translate="label">
      <reference name="header">
    <block type="page/header" name="header">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/customheader.phtml</template></action> 
    </block> 
</reference> 
</cms_index_index>
```

Don't forget to create `customheader.phtml`